# Finite Intersection of uniformly convex Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $X=W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $Y=W_{0}^{s,p}(\Omega)$ be the classical and fractional Sobolev spaces. Both are uniformly convex Banach spaces. Let $Z=X\cap Y$ be the space under the norm
$$
\|z\|_Z=\|z\|_X+\|z\|_Y.
$$
Then it can be easily seen that $Z$ is a Banach space.

But I am unable to predict whether $Z$ is uniformly convex under the above norm, which would also give the reflexivity since uniform convex spaces are reflexive.

Comment: Why is $X\cap Y$ a Banach space? You need some kind of compatibility between $X$ and $Y$ else it shouldn't work.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Yes, there should be compatibility between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Indeed, I have edited the question a little with two kinds of Sobolev spaces. Now $Z$ is a Banach space, since both $X$ and $Y$ are compactly embedded in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: Is you main target the uniform convexity? Or maybe only the reflexivity? For reflexivity you could notice the all norm on a finite dimensional space are equivalent. So on $\mathbb{R}^2$ you could use $||.||_p$ instead of $||.||_1$. So switching to $|| (||z||_X,||z||_Y) ||_p$ would solve the question of uniform convexity and reflexivity (but using an equivalent norm).

Comment: Thanks. But here $X$ and $Y$ are not finite dimensional space. @dmw64

Comment: @Mathlover Yes, of course not. But you are taking the respective norms $||z||_X$ and $||z||_Y$ which belong infinite-dim. spaces. But then you apply the $|.|_1$ norm to the pair $(||z||_X,||z||_Y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. So you could change $|.|_1$ to $|.|_p$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and still your resulting norm would be equivalent :-D. Just in case the reflexivity is the real thing you are aiming at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is enough to notice that, for any $s\geq 0$ we have  $$
X\cap Y = W^{k,p}_0(\Omega), \quad \hbox{where}\quad k=\max\{1,s\}.
$$
Then, since $W^{k,p}_0$ is uniformly convex (as you said on your post), we deduce the uniform convexity of the intersection.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how this intersection become $W_{0}^{k,p}(\Omega)$? Indeed, I have assumed $0<s<1$ so the intersection should be $W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Can you kindly help how does it follow? Indeed, you mean to say that any $u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$ belong to $W_{0}^{s,p}(\Omega)$.